# Windows 7 custom Credential Provider - getting information from UAC prompt

Tags: windows, uac, credentials, provider

I'm trying to create Credential Provider with CPUS_CREDUI usage scenario support. I need to get information from UAC prompt about the program that is trying to run with administrative privileges. Is it possible to do this from inside the Credential Provider?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and the CPUS_CREDUI you mentioned is the correct scenario for doing this.

A good place to start is this [MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169014%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) providing overview of how credential providers work, including the UAC case.

Then there are credential provider [code samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5372), which are a good place to start implementing your own credential provider.
Inside it, there is SampleCredUICredentialProvider demonstrating how to handle the CPUS_CREDUI scenario.